# Couldn't load pyspark data frame to decision tree algorithm. It says can't work with pyspark data frame

Tags: sql, apache-spark, scikit-learn, pyspark, ibm-cloud

I was working on IBM's data platform. I was able to load data into the pyspark data frame and made a spark SQL table. After splitting the data set, then feeding it into the Classification algorithm. It rises errors like spark SQL data can't load. required ndarrays.

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor`
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split`
from sklearn import preprocessing`
import numpy as np`

X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size = 0.1,random_state = 42)
RM = RandomForestRegressor()
RM.fit(X_train.reshape(1,-1),y_train)`
```

Error:

> TypeError: Expected sequence or array-like, got {<}class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>

after this error, I did something like this:

```py
x = spark.sql('select Id,YearBuilt,MoSold,YrSold,Fireplaces FROM Train').toPandas()
y = spark.sql('Select SalePrice FROM Train where SalePrice is not null').toPandas()
```

Error:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>         5 X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size = 0.1,random_state = 42)
>         6 RM = RandomForestRegressor()
>   ----> 7 RM.fit(X_train.reshape(1,-1),y_train)
>   /opt/ibm/conda/miniconda3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in **getattr**(self, name)
>      5065             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
>      5066                 return self[name]
>   -> 5067             return object.**getattribute**(self, name)
>      5068 
>      5069     def **setattr**(self, name, value):
>   AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Comment: Please give us a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples).

Comment: I've done something like this,                                                                              
x = spark.sql('select Id,YearBuilt,MoSold,YrSold,Fireplaces FROM Train').toPandas()
y = spark.sql('Select SalePrice FROM Train where SalePrice is not null').toPandas()

Comment: Edit your question to include the example(s) with supporting code.

Comment: I have edited the question and also added a code snippet.

Comment: `X_train.values.reshape(1,-1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the sklearn documentation says:

```
"""
    X : array-like or sparse matrix, shape = [n_samples, n_features]
"""
regr = RandomForestRegressor()
regr.fit(X, y)
```

So firstly you're trying to give as the X argument a `pandas.DataFrame` instead of an `array`.

Secondly the reshape() method is not an attribute of the `DataFrame` object but `numpy array`.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[2,3,4], [5,6,7]]) 
np.reshape(x, (3, -1))
```

Hope this helps.